# Como Llenar un combo Box en Java desde otra clase Usando MySql

Tags: java, mysql, combobox

Resulta que he creado una clase con interfaz en java conjuntamente NetBeans. Pues tengo un combo que lo lleno con el resultado de una consulta pero a la hora de abrir un nuevo frame inserto un dato a mysql y cuando se cierra quiero que se actualice automáticamente. Ya intenté con un evento de windows `close` pero no lo hace. Acá les dejo mi código:

```
//este método lo uso para llenar el combo con una consulta MySQL
//esta es la clase Alta.java
void llena_combo() {

    try {
        jComboBox1.removeAllItems();
        jComboBox3.removeAllItems();
        jComboBox2.removeAllItems();
        Statement st=cn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("Select * from unidades");
        while(rs.next())
        {                
            jComboBox1.addItem(rs.getString("unidad"));
            jComboBox3.addItem(rs.getString("unidad"));
            jComboBox2.addItem(rs.getString("unidad"));

        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Alta.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);
    }     
}

//Ahora en la clase Unidades.java inserto datos y quiero que cuando el usuario cierre la ventana se actualce automaticamente el combo de la clase Alta.java ya lo intente con el evento

private void formWindowClosed(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
      Alta fr = new Alta();
      fr.llena_combo();
}
//como pueden observar genero un objeto de la clase Alta y ese objeto manda a traer al metodo llena_combo pero no lo hace incluso probe meter el metodo jCombobox.removeAllItems() y si lo hace pero no me explico por que no quiere actualizar mi con el metodo para llenar el combo 
//EL combobox es public static pero no hace nada
```

Comment: No solo a las mujeres les cuesta la programación, a los varones también. Y también conozco mujeres que programan mucho mejor que varios conocidos varones ;). Arriba los ánimos y que la diferencia de género no sea un bloqueante para el aprendizaje.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No debe utilizar múltiples `JFrame`. Una aplicación sólo debe tener un solo. Usted DEBE hacer uso de un `JDialog` de para las ventanas hijas.

```
public class Form2 extends JDialog{...}
```

Es responsabilidad de la ventana hija actualizar  Así que cuando se hace clic en el botón "Guardar" del cuadro de diálogo.  El código `ActionListener` tiene que hacer dos cosas:

1. Actualizar la base de datos con el nuevo valor
2. Actualizar el cuadro combinado con el nuevo valor. Así que esto significa que cuando se crea el JDialog que necesita para aprobar el cuadro combinado (o el ComboBoxModel) como un parámetro a esa clase para que pueda actualizar el cuadro combinado. O, lo que necesita para devolver un valor desde el diálogo de manera que cuando se cierra el diálogo puede actualizar el cuadro combinado.

Es recomendable agregar elementos a tu combo a través  de un `model` por ejemplo `DefaultComboBoxModel`

```
static DefaultComboBoxModel modelo;//declarar static e instanciarla en tu contructor`
public Jfram1() {
    initComponents();
    modelo = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
   llena_combo(); // llenar los datos al ejecutar el programa
}
```

Tu método llenar combo podría ser algo así

```
static void llena_combo(){ // static para poder llamarlo desde el otro frame o JDialog

try {
    modelo.removeAllElements(); // eliminamos lo elementos
    Statement st=cn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("Select * from unidades");
    while(rs.next())
    {                
        modelo.addElement(rs.getString("unidad"));
    }
     combo.setModel(modelo); // seteamos el modelo y se cargan los datos
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Alta.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);
}
```

y el Evento windowClosing de tu segundo form donde agregas los datos a la base de datos seria

```
public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent) {
        if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
            "Está seguro que desea Salir?", "Desea Salir?", 
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
            dispose();
            Jfram1.llenarCombo();
        }
```

Comment: gracias amigo me sirvió bastante SALUDOS DESDE MEXICO!!!! :)

Comment: Ánimo. Con dedicación se pueden lograr muchas cosas. Saludos desde Perú